# When can a function $f$ dominate $g$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification, analytic-functions

Let $f,g$ two positive functions ($\ge 0$) with domain $[-1,1]$ .

We want to describe conditions of $f$ and $g$ that leads to the conclusion that $f$ can dominate $g$ according to the following definition:

> Definition : $f$ dominates $g$ if it exists $k>0$ so that $kf(x) \ge g(x)$ for every $x \in [-1,1]$.

--- MY THOUGHTS: One necessary condition is that $f(x)=0 \rightarrow g(x)=0$ i.e. the points where $f$ is null shall be also points where $g$ is null. In fact for such a point $x_0$, $kf(x_0)$ will be equal to zero for every value of $k$ and therefore could never dominate $g$ if $g(x_0)>0$.

This is not enough though, because for example $f(x)=x^4$ cannot dominate $g(x)=x^2$ for any value of $k$. The order of the Taylor expansion at $0$ forces $kf(x)$ to go faster to zero than $g(x)$ for every value of $k$. So this suggests a statement.

--- STATEMENT: Let $f,g$ be positive and analytic and suppose that on the border they are strictly positive. If $\overline x$ is such that $f(\overline x)=0$ one should have that $g(\overline x)=0$. Further, let  the infinitesimal order of $f$ at $\overline x$ be $2k$ (so that the first $2k-1$ derivatives are $0$) and for $g$ let it be $2m$. Than if $k \le m$, $f$ can majorize $g$ in the sense above.

I took even orders of expansion because if the order was odd locally it could have negative values, which is against the assumptions on $f$ and $g$.

Is my reasoning correct ? Or can it be improved to reach a correct statement ? Are there weaker conditions ?

Comment: I do not thing such characterization is possible because the two functions can oscillate, each at a different frequency.

Comment: Not getting what you want to say…. Just to clarify if f and g have no zeros (and are continuos) it is easy to make kf >g uniformly. Just take k to be larger than the ratio max g / min f to make kf dominate g. max and min are finite because of the continuity of the functions and the compactness of the interval. So one has just to see what happens near the zeros I think.

Comment: Maybe you were not considering that I said that f and g are positive functions ? (first line of my post)

Comment: Such an absolute constant $k$ does not exists. $k$ must be a function of $g(x)$.

Comment: Ah ok. I am not looking for a constant independent on f ang g. I am asking myselft if such a constant exists for a fixed f,g couple. This constant does not exist for every f,g couple, i.e. it is not always true that f can majorize g. See the discussion for an example. So the task is to find conditions on f and g so that such a constant exists.

Comment: Well, If $f,g\in C[-1,1]$ then $f,g$ possess minimum and maximum values in $[-1,1]$ and you go from there. So, continuity up to the boundary is sufficient.

Comment: I appreciate your interest but I presented my question with a certain amount of reasonings. Please read my question carefully and answer point to point. I provided some examples that I would like you to comment on and consider when providing comments/answers. It is not nice to answer without taking into consideration the OP (me in this case). Thank you

Comment: The conditions in your suggested statements are insufficient: consider the functions $cos(x)+sin(x)+1$ and $cos(x)-sin(x)+1$.

Comment: Please write an answer motivating your counterexample. Thanks :)